# Create a Trello card without a checklist

Tags: trello

Most of my Trello cards don't need checklists. I used to add them manually as needed. Now, whenever I create a new card on the website, it automatically adds a blank checklist called "Checklist". I've searched through the settings but I can't see any way of controlling this behaviour. The mobile app still doesn't add checklists unless you add them yourself.

At the moment I have to delete the checklist from every card when I create it. Is there a way to revert to the old behaviour?

#### EDIT 1

I've just added a card to my work Trello, and it didn't add a checklist. The difference between my work and personal Trellos is that I had set up my personal one with a team, but not my work one. I've just created a team for my work Trello and added the board to it, but I don't have a need to create another card just yet. I'll see what happens next time.

Comment: Do you have use any automation tools with your board, like Butler or Zapier?

Comment: @rahi It's a brand new vanilla account.

Comment: Any news on this one? I'm currenty having the same problem with a newly created account.

Comment: @SebastianStern See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've just received a reply from Trello support:

> [...] those automatic checklists were part of an experiment the Trello team was running on certain elements of the Trello interface, and it looks like you were in that experiment bucket. The team is removing that automatic checklist feature, as you weren't alone in not liking it, so that'll be gone soon, if it isn't already.

So basically, it was an A/B test, and I was in the B group. Those with accounts in the A group couldn't replicate the issue because they were in the control group.

#### EDIT - 8 May 2018

I sent a follow-up email on 5 May 2018 because the checklists were still being applied automatically. Here is the reply:

> In regards to your question, while we don't have an ETA, I've spoken to my team about your situation and they've let me know that you can disable the checklists for your browser with this link: https://trello.com/support/try?experimentName=expandedCardBack&variationName=control&time=31104000&version=1
>
> Please note you'll need to visit that link again if you change browsers.

I've tested this method, and it works. Note that as they said, you'll have to do this in every browser you use Trello on.